# Replace single line break with double line break

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$str =
'hello
world';
```

And I want to replace single line breaks to double line breaks, so we have:

```
$str =
'hello

world';
```

I tried:

```
$str = str_replace("\n", "\n\n", $str);
```

But it did not work. What's the correct approach? Can we use `PHP_EOL`...?

Comment: Is it really a \n after hello or is it \r\n? What platform are you on? Is this for display on a web page or on a command line? For the command line PHP_EOL should work but not for a web page of course.

Comment: https://eval.in/1048568

Comment: [That looks like it works fine to me](https://3v4l.org/dLHMq). Is there a chance your original string actually uses `\r\n`?

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: you can check here https://www.ideone.com/2h2zQV

Comment: It sometimes helps me to use [VarDumper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) to see the real content of variables because var_dump sometimes swallows up important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To don't think about EOL format, you can use regex to find and clone  it. `\R` works with any EOL char combination

```
$str = preg_replace("/(\R)/", "$1$1", $str);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/1048569)

Answer (score 0):

You approach is working but you need an plain/text output header to see it working on the browser.

```
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
```